# Java build error w/o apperant reason

Tags: java, ant

I am working on a project that is going on for several months now.
Suddenly when compiling we get the error:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

After adding the -Xlint the above message disappear but the only error we get is:

```
[javac] 1 error
```

There are however about 45 warning. most of them not new.
Could it be that there is some new warning that I missed that cause the compilation to fail?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the project builds properly on eclipse.
once a week we build using ant to product a version for the server.
I just want to know if there is a way to pin point the problem otherwise I guess I would have to review last 30 commits or go fix warning by warning.

Edit 2:
Problem fixed. I am not sure what it was exactly but I suspect that editing the my module.gwt.xml using external editor which might have miss-guessed the file encoding, inserted some non-visible characters with a wrong encoding which in turn caused the compiler to give an error w/o a proper description. (maybe I don't know)

So what lessons should I take from this?  handle all warning? (not sure that is always possible.)
using a jenkins? (as @Jayan suggested) the project manager would never approve investing time on such things in my company.

Comment: @aioobe what does the apprivitation 'SSCCE' mean?

Comment: The first one, is it an error or a warning? It should be related to generics...

Comment: @reporter, ask google...

Comment: @kroiz Have you tried to compile your source code without ant? So you can verify there are no errors in general.

Comment: @reporter, yes in eclipse the project compiles and run fine.

Comment: @aioobe, I don't think it is possible to write a SSCCE in this case. because I don't know what part of my application is causing the error.

Comment: @kroiz - please post the real output from compiler

Comment: ... also, consider passing the suggested `-Xlint:unchecked` parameter to the compiler to see what is incorrect.

Comment: @Duncan Jones, as stated in the original question, I added that flag but then the I only get "1 error" and no explanation or reason.

Comment: @kroiz Sorry! Clearly my brain is not working yet today.

Comment: @kroiz - unrelated rant. You need to have a CI. In that case one checkin which broke the build will be more obvious- See http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html.  My favorite  is Jenkins http://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: @Jayan, I guess theoretically you are right, to our defense I will say that although we did not use any program, we did pull from each other daily and built using eclipse which did not detect any problem. we just did not expect that building using ant will fail code that builds perfectly fine on eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error normally appears when you use a deprecated version of a class that now takes a Generic parameter. For example, in Java 6 and earlier, `JList` treated everything as Objects, and it was up to the programmer to cast everything correctly. In Java 7, `JList` is now `JList<E>`, with the parameter being the type of Objects contained in the list. `JList` (without generics) will still work, but you will get an error like the one you are experiencing.

EDIT: The reason, by the way, that these operations are considered unsafe is that, without the generics, types cannot be compared at compile time, and must be checked at runtime.

Comment: I see, but really the issue is if there is a way to locate the problem w/o starting to code review last week work of two other programmers? I mean what are compilers for anyway?!

Comment: If everything is being cast correctly, this will never cause a crash. In terms of finding where the errors are, there isn't an easy way other than looking through for classes that should be using generics and aren't. Looking for occurrences of casts is a good start. The other way is to start running lots of tests and see if any runtime errors happen (would only locate problems if the casts are not done correctly). Other than that I don't know of any easy way to isolate these errors.

Comment: @kroiz additional: just checked eclipse, it will give you a warning at every line where this is done incorrectly, along the lines of `X is a raw type. References to generic type X<E> should be parameterized` so going through and finding and removing warnings should get rid of this error

Comment: I tried to suppress the warning instead of fixing them. that did not work. I still received the error even after suppressing all those generic warnings. I think I will try to build from eclipse since it builds nicely from it.

Comment: If you're talking about `@SuppressWarning` this suppresses warnings, not compile errors. If you have found the line you need to suppress, and know what type of object is being used with the class, you could just add the type in angle brackets (e.g. so `ArrayList a = new ArrayList();` would become `ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();` if it contains Strings) This will both remove the warning and cause errors to show anywhere it is being used incorrectly.